# Locked out of Debian embedded device after mistake in fstab

Tags: linux, debian, mount, root, fstab

I am working with an embedded Linux device with Debian 9 installed. The device has an internal storage and the option to extend the storage with a sd card. I want to use the extra sd card for additional storage and I configured it to be mounted at boot in /etc/fstab.

However, after reboot I am unable to access my device. I can ping its IP but my attempst to connect through ssh are refused. The device provides a serial port for debugging to which I have connected using Putty and where I have discovered my mistake in the fstab:

```
Unrecognized mounting option default or missing value
```

That is, I have written *default* instead of *defaults* in /etc/fstab. Now I am well aware of my mistake but I have no idea of how to solve it. I cannot type anything in the serial port. It says:

```
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -x
Cannot open access to console, the root account is locked.
See sulogin(8) man page for more details.
```

The command prompt mentions the option to enter the BIOS menu at boot by pressing DEL it does not recognize that key being pressed.

I cannot access the internal storage where the fstab is. 
Removing the extra sd card does not work either because the system searchs for it at boot.
The device has a reset button that is not working anymore.

Is anything I can do to access my device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally been able to update the firmware using an option in the bootloader menu.

I have been able to access the bootloader menu using a different terminal for the serial communication. First I thought that the problem of the DEL key pressing not being recognized was related to the lock of the root account. However, using [Tera Term](http://ttssh2.osdn.jp/index.html.en) instead of Putty, pressing DEL has been recognized at boot.

Answer (score 0):

What is the device ?

Since:

- `fstab` is faulty.
- your root account is locked.

You won't be able to recover this way.
The only way to recover is:

- Entering the bootloader and make your device boot using NFS or directly on the SD-Card (and then your repair the embedded storage). Often, embedded devices use `uboot` which is an Open Source well documented bootloader that is able to boot using several medium.
- Use a tool provided by your board manufacturer (for example boards from Amlogic can be totally flashed from scratch with `USB Burning tool`, Android devices can using fastboot or others manufacturer tools like EMMA for sony phones) to totally rework your device.